# Write XML with SQL Command

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, sqlcommand

I have problem with SQLCommand for XML. Actually I'm newbie

I have 2 tables:

1. table `Customer_BSM`:

   ```
   id_Cust | Name    | Omset   | Colour  | seq
   ---------------------------------------------
   1001    | Ali     | 10      | Black   | 1
   2001    | Bhudi   | 5       | Red     | 2
   3001    | charlie | 20      | yellow  | 3
   ```
2. table `address_BSM`:

   ```
   id_cust | Address  | no1    | no2
   -----------------------------------
   1001    | Jln 1    | 1A     | 2A
   1001    | Jln 2    | 1B     | 2B
   2001    | street 1 | S1     | S2
   3001    | gang A   | AG     | BG
   ```

Now, I want to select and create xml with sql command, especially with "for xml". How to write the sql command?

the result, maybe like this

```
 <customer_BSM id="1">
     <id_cust>1001<id_cust>
     <Name>Ali</Name>
     <omset>10</omset>
     <colour>black</colour>
     <addres_bsm>
        <address>jln 1</address>
        <no1>1A</no1
        <no2>2A</no2>
     </addres_bsm>
     <addres_bsm>
        <address>jln 2</address>
        <no1>1B</no1
        <no2>2B</no2>
     </addres_bsm>
 </customer_BSM>
 <customer_BSM id="2">
     <id_cust>2001<id_cust>
     <Name>Bhudi</Name>
     <omset>5</omset>
     <colour>red</colour>
     <addres_bsm>
        <address>street 1 </address>
        <no1>S1</no1
        <no2>S2</no2>
     </addres_bsm>
 </customer_BSM>
 <customer_BSM id="3">
     <id_cust>3001<id_cust>
     <Name>Charlie</Name>
     <omset>20</omset>
     <colour>Yellow</colour>
     <addres_bsm>
        <address>gang A</address>
        <no1>AG</no1
        <no2>BG</no2>
     </addres_bsm>
 </customer_BSM>
```

I used this SQL Command, but not working

```
SELECT  *, (
    SELECT * 
    FROM [address_bsm] A INNER JOIN [customer_bsm] B 
    ON a.id_cust = b.id_cust
    FOR XML PATH ('Address_bsm')) 
FROM [customer_bsm]
FOR XML PATH
```

Actually, the result was not same with my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only able to test with MSSQL, but the SQL should be very similar.

```
SELECT c.[id_Cust]
      ,[Name]
      ,[Omset]
      ,[Colour]
      ,[seq]
      ,(SELECT a.[Address],a.[no1],a.[no2] FROM address_BSM a
      WHERE a.id_cust = c.id_cust
  FOR XML PATH ('address_bsm'), TYPE)
  FROM [dbo].[Customer_BSM] c
  FOR XML PATH ('customer_bsm')
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.. i trying your code in MS SQL, and i get the result. maybe you miss about ID,that represent the SEQ in table. have you and idea?  Best Regards

Comment: Just try to write as first entry of your select "seq AS [@id]", This should let the value of seq be an attribut of the top node called "id"...

Comment: I didn't see ID as an attr. and I didn't know how to do that so thanks Shungo too!